# Could you help me with this logic problem?

Tags: logic

I need help proving validity of this:

```
((A ∧ B)∨(¬A ∧¬B))<==>(A<==>B)
```

[image]

This is how we did it in class, but I don't actually understand this very well. Could someone explain to me how to do this or give me something to read instead? I was absent in class when the professor showed this and the section in our textbook doesn't completely cover this.

Comment: This is probably a better question for your TA or professor than SE, honestly. But look at what you're trying to prove: it's a statement of the form X <-> Y. You show this by first proving X -> Y and then Y -> X. Those are the two big 'branches' on your proof tree. Each of those branches is itself a proof, so try to understand how those work and you'll be done.

Comment: Yes I understood that part, but what comes next? From A^B they're getting A and -A (where does -A come from?) and from it a contradiction, from which they're again getting A?

Comment: To complete the proof in the left to right direction you need to do a disjunction elimination on ((A^B)v(~A^~B)) and show that no matter which of the disjuncts is true, (A<->B) follows. We do that by supposing (A^B) is true and derive (A<->B), and similarly for (~A^~B).

Comment: A simple way would be to just do the truth table for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is a *Natural Deduction* proof.

Here is the first part (the "short" one) :

> **[(A ∧ B)∨(¬A ∧¬B)] → (A ↔ B)**

*Proof*

1) **(A ∧ B)∨(¬A ∧¬B)** --- premise

2) **(A ∧ B)** --- assumed [a] for ∨-elimination

3) **B** --- from 2) by ∧-elimination

4) **¬B** --- assumed [c]

5) **⊥** --- from 3) and 4)

6) **(¬A ∧ ¬B)** --- assumed [b] for ∨-elimination

7) **¬B** --- from 6) by ∧-elimination

8) **A** --- assumed [d]

9) **⊥** --- from 7) and 8)

10) **⊥** --- from 2)-5) and 6)-9) and 1) by ∨-elimination, discharging [a] and [b]

11) **B** --- from 4) and 10) by *Double Negation* (or *RAA*), discharging [c]

12) **A → B** --- from 8) and 11) by →-introduction, discharging [d]

In the same way, exchanging the roles of **A** and **B**, we can derive :

13) **B → A**

14) **(A ↔ B)** --- from 12) and 13) by ↔-introduction

> 15) **[(A ∧ B)∨(¬A ∧¬B)] → (A ↔ B)** --- from 1) and 14) by  →-introduction.

Answer (score 1):

One approach for handling this type of problem, when there are only a few variables involved, is to simply write out the truth tables of the two expression and verify that, for all T/F assignments to variables, the truth values of the two statements are the same.

Comment: Yes, but the professor will have this method on the exam so I have to learn to do it this way.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about putting that disclaimer in the answer.  However, this answer could be useful to someone else who has a similar question.

Comment: @esnafga what method are you talking about exactly? It's not clear from your question.